# UI Orientation problem when using UINavigationControoler/Navigation application

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a simple navigation application. I allow all orientations for the application.
Problem is as follows
I am in landscape orientation. then i navigate from RootViewController to a UIViewController For showing the PDF. When I am in UiviewControoler i change orientation to portrait. and come back to the RootViewController. At this time the RootViewController is in landscape mode itself and it Shows whole UI badly.

I really do not know what to search on net. still i tried to search but couldn't got my answer.Can anyone tell me How to fix this problem?

Comment: on google serach navigation controller with orientation change

Comment: You should look at presentModalViewController instead of pushViewController, as push assumes the same orientation, whereas present doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You declare Boolean type variable in app delegate file and then set property and synthesize in .m file. In app-delegate.m file u

```
 - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    MidwestTestAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MidwestTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.isLandscapeLeft = TRUE;

}
else
{
    MidwestTestAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MidwestTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.isLandscapeLeft = FALSE;


}
```

}
 in .m file u use this function which give u orientation is enable or not. similarly u do for view controller.

Comment: if u not get anything then tell

Comment: I did not get the one thing variable appDelegate. can you clarify me about it?

Comment: hey got it. Thanks !  HypnosisAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (HypnosisAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: in appdelegate .h file u have to declare Boolean type variable.like Bool IsLandscapeMode; and property Boolean IsLandscapeMode;
and in appdelegate.m file synthsize IsLandscapeMode;